# In an AngularJS custom directive, can I add a built-in directive to the existing element?

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS, if a custom directive is to be used by adding an attribute:

```
<input type="text" my-directive>
```

then can I add an `ng-keypress="handleKeypress()"` to the element? ***(without modifying the original HTML, that is)***  I tried doing that in the link function:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    attrs["ngKeypress"] = "handleKeypress()";
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work.  If `attrs["ng-keypress"]` is used instead of `attrs["ngKeypress"]`, also nothing happens.  I can also use jQuery or jqLite's

```
elem.on("keypress", function(ev) { ... });
```

but I am also thinking of just using Angular's way of adding an `ngKeypress` if possible.

Comment: Have you tried <input type="text" ng-keypress="yourFunction()" my-directive> ?

Comment: the custom directive should be the one that is adding the `ng-keypress`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
link: function(scope, element) {
  element.attr('ng-keypress', 'handleKeypress()');
  element.removeAttr("my-directive"); //remove your directive attribute to restrict indefinite loops
  $compile(element)(scope);
}
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/P0NhGRSGDET6Ntx4nCnO)

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="text" ng-keypress="yourFunction()" my-directive>` will work.

Here is [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tefoqi/2/edit?html,js,console,output) for that

Comment: actually, the directive is to add the `ng-keypress`

Comment: why do you need to write your custom directive, when angular gives you the exact same directive from the box? If you want to go angular-way, you have to use angular directives when possible.

Comment: because in the `ngKeypress` handler, I will define some custom logic.  This is what I don't want to do: add this `ng-keypress` thing to 200 lines of code every where in the code base, and where does the  handler go?  Or I can add all logic to a directive and just use `my-directive` every where instead of the `ng-keypress`.

Comment: The handler will go to your function which is defined in your current scope for this elements. So if you need 50 times to use one logic and 30 some other isn't it better to write the same ng-keypress="myFunc" and create 2-3 different controllers which will override this myFunc in it's scope.

Comment: or, if you have one custom logic for all ng-keypress you just define controller on parent element of all your inputs and in each 200 input you just put ng-keypress="yourFunc()". in your controller you define scope.yourFunc = function and it will be used in all 200 cases. To use different handler, just create child controller and rewrite your scope.yourFunc

Comment: well, then it might become "why do you ever want a custom directive?"  The fact is, sometimes we want to encapsulate everything in a directive.  We just use the directive in the HTML and be done with it, instead of doing the low level stuff every single time.

Comment: if I add the `ng-keypress` to the element in the `link` function, for sure I will use isolate scope, so I will need to define a `scope.handleKeypress = function() { }` inside my link function

Comment: That's up to you, but still can't understand why would you create new directive, when you have an existing one. You could do it without isolated scopes and without additional complexity. Just adding handler to the scope and using `ng-keypress` for what it was created for. But that's ok, everyone writes however he sees his program. I guess @codeninja.sj suggested something you want.

Comment: NO.  The directive is to add a bunch of functionalities to the element, and ONE OF WHICH IS handled by keypress

Comment: if you have ONE OF WHICH then you can use directive for other functionality. From your post I can't say if you have other functionality. IMO, it's better to use angular ng-keypress directive to handle THIS ONE functionality on keypress, if you wanted "Angular's way". It's made for this. and put the rest functionality in directive. Anyway use whatever you find better for your exact case.

Comment: If the question is how to add `ngKeypress` inside of a directive, then it may be going too far if you say you don't need a directive